# Unable to remove a whitespace that has appeared at the top of my website

Tags: wordpress, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove the white space at the top of my Wordpress website.

https://www.productlondondesign.com/

[White at top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58DFi.png)

I have tried to inspect the page and figure out what is causing it to remove it via style.cc but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Please add a [mre] of the issue here per [ask]. Your link will change/break over time and nuke all value for future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your container has a padding:

Just add this up in the "Additional CSS" section of the customizer i.e., https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVcJP.png

```
#main-content.container {
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

https://www.productlondondesign.com/wp-admin/customize.php

Please mark this answer as solved/accepted if it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your HTML, there is an empty P inside main content. this P push content down
[image]

If you remove it (or display none or remove margin) it fixes the problem

[image]

Also, try to learn how to use the inspector so you can find those issues, this kind of problem may not go well on stack overflow

Comment: tip: i found it by using the inspector target to target the white space and removing the elemnts until i got an result removing main-content. after that, i inspected the insides and found the issue. Also i recommend you to clean your HTML. empty elements like that isn't always a good sign